# Workaround to hide link popup

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

So basically after pressing the link inside the amp-story, popup appears. If I remember correctly it was intended, so the interaction doesn't get blended with the one coming from navigation or something like that. But despite this, I would still like to redirect to different pages without that popup. Is there any way to prevent it from appearing and go directly to the desired link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current spec, if you place the link in the bottommost 20% of the page, and add the attribute `show-tooltip="auto"`, the tooltip will not be shown.  Note that if it extends outside of this region, the tooltip will be shown.